# Why is statsmodels select_order function different from params for AR model?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
import pandas_datareader.data as web   

start = '2007-01-01'
end = '2015-01-01'
get_px = lambda x: web.DataReader(x, 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']    
symbols = ['SPY','TLT','MSFT']
# raw adjusted close prices
data = pd.DataFrame({sym:get_px(sym) for sym in symbols})
# log returns
lrets = np.log(data/data.shift(1)).dropna()   

# Select best lag order for MSFT returns    
max_lag = 30
mdl = smt.AR(lrets.MSFT).fit(maxlag=max_lag, ic='aic', trend='nc')
est_order = smt.AR(lrets.MSFT).select_order(maxlag=max_lag, ic='aic', trend='nc')

print('best estimated lag order = {}'.format(est_order))
print mdl.params
```

The output would be this.

```
best estimated lag order = 23
L1.MSFT    -0.075405
L2.MSFT    -0.067423
L3.MSFT     0.031371
L4.MSFT    -0.063610
L5.MSFT    -0.045080
L6.MSFT    -0.001510
L7.MSFT    -0.051875
L8.MSFT    -0.015192
L9.MSFT    -0.018665
L10.MSFT    0.044720
L11.MSFT    0.041655
L12.MSFT    0.034231
L13.MSFT   -0.042473
L14.MSFT   -0.008583
L15.MSFT    0.022171
L16.MSFT    0.009983
L17.MSFT    0.038606
L18.MSFT   -0.073060
dtype: float64
```

The problem here is that even though statsmodels decided that the ideal lag for AR model is 23, there are only 18 parameters when you check the parameters. Shouldn't it be the same ?  It would probably makes sense if the number of order from "select_order" is less than the length of parameters array. I understand that "select_order" decide the ideal lag order using AIC criteria in this case.

Can someone explain why ?  Assuming that 23 is indeed the ideal lag order, how do I get additional 5 parameters since I can only get up to 18 parameters here?

Comment: According to the code, the default `method` differs, "cmle" in fit and "mle" in select_order. Try with the same method argument.

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the 23 lags contribute to the fit - if they are zero, they get dropped and don't count.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that maxlag is just that; the highest number of lags that statsmodels' select_order method can select as the best number of lags. If the best number of lags that select_order would choose is larger than your maxlag, it will not necessary choose maxlag. It may choose a second best number of lags which may be lower than maxlag. Suppose if maxlag was infinitely large, select_order would select 15. If your maxlag is 10, it does not necessary pick that 10 as the best number of lags because it is closest to the ideal number of 15. Instead, it will look into the possible 10 lags and resolve the problem; choosing the best number of lags given the constraint that that number can not exceed 10. That number may very well turn out to be, say, 7 if the information criterion is in a better condition than if the number were 10.